# Delete APDU command with SSD AID in its data field, returns 6985

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I have a Javacard which contains a SSD (Supplementary Security Domain) and I want to delete it. Normally when I want to delete an applet or a package from my card, I send the following *DELETE APDU* command after a successful *Mutual Authentication* process (No MAC or data field encryption is required and `Security Level == 0` is enough for *DELETE APDU* command):

```
--> 80 E4 00 00 LC 4F <AID Len> <AID>
<-- 90 00
```

The command above works fine for normal applets. But when I put the AID of my SSD in it, then the card responds with *69 85* status words, which means *"Conditions of use not satisfied."*.

Since *Delegated Management* feature is enabled in my card and a *Public Token* key and a *Receipt* key are loaded in the ISD, I thought maybe the mentioned error is due to not using the *Delete Token* in the *DELETE APDU* command. So I calculated the *Delete Token* as below:

Global Platform Card Specification 2.2.0.7 : Figure C-8: Delete Token Calculation
[image]

```
DeleteToken = RSA_Sign("00 00 LC 4F <SSD AID Len> <SSD AID>", TokenPrivateKey)
```

And then I tried to delete the SSD using the follwing command:

```
--> 80 E4 00 00 <LC+Len(DeleteToken)> 4F <SSD AID Len> <SSD AID> 9E <Len(DeleteToken> <DeleteToken>
<-- 69 85
```

But I got the 6985 status words again. Does anyone have any idea where the problem is and how I can solve it?

**Update:**

I even tried the *DELETE APDU* command with `P2 = 0x80` to delete the SSD with all the related objects. But it failed too:

```
-->  80 E4 00 80 09 4F <SSD AID Len> <SSD AID>
<--  6A 86 (= Incorrect P1 or P2 parameter)
```

**Update2:**

I even tried to send the DELETE APDU command in a secure channel (SecLevel = 03). But again, I received 6985 status words. Which hash algorithm am I need to use to generate the Delete Token? As far as I know, The GP Specification doesn't specify the hash algorithm.

**Update3:**

The mentioned SSD is instanciated from the card's ISD package with `0E` privilege, which means:

*Security Domain* + *Delegated Management* + *DAP verification*

**Update4:**

I think I found the issue!

Quouted from **[2.1.1_Mapping_guidelines_v1.0.1-Final.pdf](https://globalplatform.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/2.1.1_Mapping_guidelines_v1.0.1-Final.pdf)**:

> **6.1. DELETE**
>
> **6.1.2. Recommendation**
>
> **Data Field Sent in the Command Message**
>
> (blah blah)
>
> ***On an implementation supporting Supplementary Security Domains, if an attempt is being made to delete an instance of a Supplementary Security Domain and the Supplementary Security Domain has the DAP Verification privilege (bit 7 of the privileges byte set), the Security Domain is not deleted and a response of '6985' is returned.***

**Question1: Any idea why it is implemented/recommended like this? What is the purpose of making this type of SSD (SSD with DAP Verification privilege) non-removable?**

**Update5:**

I've tried to change the priveleges of my SSD to remove *DAP Verification* privelege from it using *INSTALL For REGISTRY UPDATE* and then delete the SSD. But it failed with `6A 80` status words (Which means "The parameters in the data field are incorrect").

```
-->  00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
<--  6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF 90 00

-->  80 50 00 00 08 DF 4B 4B B7 15 35 5A 93
<--  00 00 41 89 00 24 94 97 41 21 01 02 00 77 5C 2B 50 27 5A F4 8A 18 C0 8B 2D C2 20 50 90 00

-->  84 82 00 00 10 30 AD 04 C4 60 A2 80 8B 5A 61 7E 49 3A 39 B6 C6
<--  90 00

-->  80 E6 40 00 16 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 07 <SSD AID> 01 80 00 00
<--  6A 80
```

**Question2: What's wrong with the *INSTALL For Registry Update* command?**

Comment: > Question1: 

The same spec says some lines above: "On an implementation supporting Supplementary Security Domains, the DELETE command is able to
delete an instance of a Supplementary Security Domain that has the DAP Verification privilege, however,
a Security Domain with the Mandated DAP privilege cannot be deleted." This section is somehow inconsistent. For Mandated DAP this makes sense, otherwise by deleting the SSD it would be possible to circumvent the mandatory DAP checks for applet management. For SSD with just DAP, not. Maybe the developers just followed the spec here.

Answer (score 0):

The delegated management token when using RSA should use SHA-1 as hashing mechanism with the PKCS#1 scheme. I have some untested [signing code](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/blob/master/globalplatform/src/crypto.c#L1096) and for assembling the [token data](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/blob/master/globalplatform/src/globalplatform.c#L3338). Maybe this is helpful as a start.

Regarding Question2:

I have not done this before, but you are passing the SSD AID and as application AID again the . The application AID is only needed if you want to modify privileges of an application, e.g. the default selected privilege.

Instead:

```
80 E6 40 00 16 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 07 <SSD AID> 01 80 00 00
```

I would give this one a try:

```
80 E6 40 00 16 <Length SSD AID> <SSD AID> 00 01 80 00 00
```

Comment: I tried them, but they all failed. P2=0x80 solution log added to the question. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the SSD just cannot be deleted? E.g in eUICCs there is a ECASD and deleting it would kill most of the card functionality.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that it is deletable, because I myself instanciated and installed this SSD.